# Nature of acceleration from $x$ vs $t$ graph

Tags: calculus

[image]

The figure approximately shows the $x$-coordinate of a particle as a function of time. How can we decide whether the accelerations at time $t_1,t_2,t_3$ are positive or negative?

Comment: Look up the definition of concave and convex at a point for a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acceleration is the concavity of the graph.  So the acceleration is +,-,+ at the three times, respectively,

Comment: Thank you.But can you explain why concavity indicates acceleration?

Comment: Acceleration is the second derivative of position.  A function is concave up when its second derivative is positive, and concave down when its second derivative is negative.